# Why "let a = [1, 2, 3]; console.log(a === [1, 2, 3]);" is "false" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a === [1, 2, 3]);
```

is "false" in JavaScript?

Comment: Search for 'JavaScript Comparing Arrays' yields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Because they are 2 different objects. Their value are the same though, but you doesn't compare those.

Comment: @soorapadman Your linked question has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: He is not asking how, he is asking why...

Answer (score 3):

Javascript Objects are a bit like C pointers.

`a` contains the memory address of the first array you define.

When you do `console.log(a === [1, 2, 3]);` you are in fact creating a new array, and you compare its memory value with the one you kept in `a`.

That's why:

```
const a = []; 
a.push(1)
```

is valid (the constant is the "pointer", not the array)

Answer (score 0):

Because the arrays aren't the same. The variable `a` contains a different array than the one in the `console.log` even though the array values are the same. You would have to loop through both arrays and compare each value of both to determine if they were equal.